# error on sitecore content editor "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'treelist' Key being added: 'treelist'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We restarted our app pool and trying to login to content editor of sitecore, we are gettting the below error as in teh screen shot.
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'treelist'  Key being added: 'treelist'

http://screencast.com/t/qo8CWojCqZpR

we are not able to enter content editor.

If you guys have experienced it before, could you please help me?

cheers

Comment: Can you just try to recycle it again? Also, do you have any custom treelist-like field types?

Comment: Hi mark, no we do not have any custom treelist like field types. I restarted apppool and the iis too. It does not work. quite strange, it was fine all the way when we are working, only after the recycle, it started giving this issue.

Comment: I recommend you submit a Sitecore support ticket with your web.config, logs, and the error.

Comment: Hi mark, yeah... you are right. there is a custom tree list field type added by some one yesterday which i never expected.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the stacktrace you can see that the fieldtypemanager tries to get the implementation based on the name in configuration.
It appears the FieldTypes.config contains 2 items with the same name.
Solving issues like this is not complicated, Reflector is your friend while doing Sitecore development.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. This problem occurs if you try to add a custom control of similar name as the existing sitecore field (in this case custom tree list field type added). To solve the problem:

- Login Sitecore in desktop mode.
- Click in Start/Sitecore -> Development Tools -> Developer Center
- In developer Center -> go to View -> Content Explorer
- Finally - you will be able to see a small Content Editor, where at the top you can select Core Database.
- Here you go to system in content tree -> select the extra control created -> delete.

This solved my problem, I hope it solves yours too!